# Long variable naming with chained filters on API best practices?

Tags: api-design, naming, variables

I am writing an application where a single variable may be affected by different filters applied to the data that's read from the DB. Each different variation has to be stored (as each one serves different purposes) in different variables, however, I'm not sure about the best naming convention for this cases as it will become a public-accessible API at some point. A simple example:

- `meterPrice`: original name.
- `meterPriceBySuburb`: new variable with a *suburb* filter.
- `meterPriceBySuburbByType`: new variable with the *suburb* **and** *type* filters.
- `meterPriceBySuburbByTypeBySchool`: you get the point.

I have 2 main concerns with the naming that should be followed for these variables:

1. Some variables names, following this format, can get *way too long*, the longer one we are planning on creating being something like: `MeterPriceDistributionChartDataBySuburbByTypeBySimilarity`. Does the longitude itself be a problem on a public-facing API?
2. What is the convention or, at least, the best practice for chaining these filters? Currently I have thought about 4 different schemas:

   - `meterPriceBySuburbTypeSimilarity`: One after another after first `By`.
   - `meterPriceBySuburbByTypeBySimilarity`: Having `By` before each filter.
   - `meterPriceBySuburbAndTypeAndSimilarity`: Having a first `By` and then follow each new one with `And`.
   - `meterPriceBySuburbTypeAndSimilarity`: Having an initial `By` and just add `And`to the final filter.

Thanks in advance for any responses! And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why do they have to be individual variables? Can you not have a single `meterPrice` map where the keys are the list of filters?

Comment: Hi @casablanca! Unfortunately, I need to store them in a single row, in a single SQL table. If I was using something like MongoDB that would be the best approach! However in this case, I couldn't think of something better than naming them with the appropriate filter applied appended. I cannot make use of JSON-like fields (Postgres has some of them) as we constantly export this information to CSV which, in the end, will have to use the same, long, variable names. Do you think there may be another way around? Thanks for your comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my first child. His name is DancesWithWolves.

Why didn't I call him FirstChild? Because a name doesn't have to be the story of how you got the data. It could be the story of how you will use the variable. It could be the story of what the variable means to you.

But you're writing an API so you don't know how the data will be used. But at least you know the story of why you thought this query should exist. Think on that when you come up with a name. Don't get so fixated on the structure of the query. If that's all the name communicates it's little better then letting people create their own queries. Use the name to tell me why I care about the Suburb filter. At least that will be more memorable and have a chance at being meaningful and memorable outside the context of writing the query.